# C++ Logic Issue

Tags: c++

I'm trying to write a simple c++ program that outputs an objects current height once it hits a specific point. The object I'm trying to accomplish is that you have an object that starts at a varied position a moves off under a random velocity with gravity attached. If the ball collides with a wall or another object, it should move backward, with no energy loss, but still continue to fall due to gravity. Once the ball has reached a specific height, output that value.

Now, all I'm trying to do right now is check to see if my ball has gone beyond my width bounds. But for the life of me I can't see why my last if statement at the bottom wont call.

Am I missing / doing something really stupid?

```
  int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

    float velocity;
    float height, targetHeight;
    float gravity;
    float time;
    float angle;
    float width;
    float move;
    float distance; 

    gravity = 9.80f;
    time = 0;
    distance = 0;

    cout << "Set Height\n";
    cin >> height;

    cout << "Set target height\n";
    cin >> targetHeight;

    cout << "Set Angle ( 0 - 90 ): \n";
    cin >> angle;
    angle *= 3.14 * 180; // convert to radians

    cout << "Set velocity (0 - 100): \n";
    cin >> velocity;

    cout << "Set Play field Width: \n";
    cin >> width;


    while( height >= target  )
    {
        time++;
        distance += velocity * cos(angle) * time;
        height += (velocity * sin(angle) * time) - (gravity * pow(time, 2) ) / 2;
    }

    if( distance == width)
    {
            cout << "You've hit the wall\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Should you have `targetHeight` instead of `target` in the `while`?

Comment: Shouldn't you also check to see if distance == 0 to see if it hits the other wall? Also, what if the ball is moving fast enough that it goes all the way through the wall? You should probably check if(distance>=width or distance<=0)

Comment: I'm always alarmed when encountering `float` equality tests!

Comment: Two have two small problems. 
1) You have not defined **target**. Just replace it by **targetHeight**. 2) Instead of **if( distance == width )**, you should write **if( distance >= width )**. If you think about it, it makes much more sense. Once you increase the variable **height**, you expect the value to become equal or bigger than width. Hope i helped

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your final `if` statement `if( distance == width )` does not test if the distance has gone beyond the width. You probably want `if( distance >= width )`. There doesn't appear to be any testing of distance traveled within your movement loop so distance could easily be greater than the width and thus cause your if to not be true.

Answer (score 1):

Move backwards at the same speed: `velocity = -velocity;`. Of course, if it's moving backwards, it may hit the other wall, so you probably want to check the `distance == 0;` as well. (Since it's floating point, I would also suggest you use `>=` and `<=` instead of exact comparisons, or you may find that the ball was one micrometer PAST the wall and then continues until it hits the sun, or you run out of math, or whatever else happens if you keep going forever).

I would further suggest that you would need the width and breadth of the "room" the ball is bouncing around in. So, in total you need X, Y, and Z coordinates of the ball.

Answer (score 1):

Note: your time ever increases, which implies a direct formula for height and distance (one saying `distance = f(time);`), but you're accumulating.

So probably you want to *assign* instead of *increment* your `distance` and `height` variables:

```
   distance = velocity * cos(angle) * time;
   height = (velocity * sin(angle) * time) - (gravity * pow(time, 2) ) / 2;
```

Next to that, you probably want to check whether the travelled `distance` *exceeds* the distance to the wall (equality with `float`s is very improbable, plus inaccurate).

Some stylistic advice: put those equations in functions of their own.